# Manipulating two tensors via loops

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose in a normal python, I have two lists: `A = [1, 2, 3]` and `B = [4, 5, 6]`. Now, I can create a new list called `C = [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]`. I can easily get this result by

```
C = list()
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        C.append(a * b)
```

In case, `A` and `B` are tensors in `tensorflow`, then are there any ways to get a tensor `C` as I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options:

*Set up:*

```
A = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
B = tf.constant([4, 5, 6])
tf.InteractiveSession()
```

1) Via broadcasting -

```
tf.reshape(tf.reshape(A, (-1,1)) * B, (-1,)).eval()
# array([ 4,  5,  6,  8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18], dtype=int32)

# reshape A to 2d array
tf.reshape(A, (-1,1)).eval()

#array([[1],
#       [2],
#       [3]], dtype=int32)

# multiply with B
(tf.reshape(A, (-1,1)) * B).eval()

#array([[ 4,  5,  6],
#       [ 8, 10, 12],
#       [12, 15, 18]], dtype=int32)
```

Flattening the tensor above gives what you need.

2) Use `einsum` -

```
tf.reshape(tf.einsum('i,j->ij', A, B), (-1,)).eval()
# array([ 4,  5,  6,  8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18], dtype=int32)

# use einsum to calculate the outer product

tf.einsum('i,j->ij', A, B).eval()
#array([[ 4,  5,  6],
#       [ 8, 10, 12],
#       [12, 15, 18]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: You make my day!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example using `tf.map_fn()` to cleverly iterate over a Tensor, and using `tf.stack()` to convert the list elements back into a Tensor.

```
A = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
B = tf.constant([4, 5, 6])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    C = list()
    for a in tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, A).eval():
        for b in tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, B).eval():
            C.append(a * b)
    C = tf.stack(C)

    print(C.eval())

'Output':
[ 4  5  6  8 10 12 12 15 18]
```